# Renaming files with criteria

Tags: regex, file, rename

Need some advice. I'm trying to do something with regular expressions that might not be possible, and if it is possible it's over my head. I can't get anything to work. I'm trying to create a tagging system for my PDF files. So if I have this file name:

```
"csharp 8 in a nutshell[studying programming csharp ebooks].pdf"
```

I would like all the words inside the '[ ]' to have a '@' in from of them. So the above file name would look like this:

```
"csharp 8 in a nutshell[@studying @programming @csharp @ebooks].pdf"
```

The problem is keeping the '@' inside the '[ ]'. For example I'd rather the 'csharp' at the very front of the file name not have the '@'.

Also, I'm using a bulk renamer called 'Bulk Rename Utility' to help me.

1. Can this be done?
2. If it can, any hints on how?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bulk Rename Utility does not support replacing multiple matches, you can only match the whole file name and perform replacements using capturing groups/backreferences.

Since you are using Windows, I suggest using Powershell:

```
cd 'C:\YOUR_FOLDER\HERE'
Get-ChildItem -File | Rename-Item -NewName { $_.Name -replace '(?<=\[[^][]*?)\w+(?=[^][]*])','@$&' }
```

See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/kF5nwK/2) and the [proof it works with .NET regex flavor](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3F%3C%3D%5C%5B%5B%5E%5D%5B%5D*%3F%29%5Cw%2B%28%3F%3D%5B%5E%5D%5B%5D*%5D%29&i=csharp%208%20in%20a%20nutshell%5Bstudying%20programming%20csharp%20ebooks%5D.pdf&r=%40%24%26).

- `(?<=\[[^][]*?)` - right before this location, there must be a `[` and then any amount of chars other than `[` and `]`, as few as possible
- `\w+` - 1+ word chars
- `(?=[^][]*])` - right after this location, there must be any amount of chars other than `[` and `]`, as many as possible, and then a `]` char.

The replacement is `@` + the whole match value (`$&`).

Also, you may use

```
Get-ChildItem -File | Rename-Item -NewName { $_.Name -replace '(\G(?!\A)[^][\w]+|\[)(\w+)','$1@$2' }
```

See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/kF5nwK/1) and [.NET regex test](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%5CG%28%3F!%5CA%29%5B%5E%5D%5B%5Cw%5D%2B%7C%5C%5B%29%28%5Cw%2B%29&i=csharp%208%20in%20a%20nutshell%5Bstudying%20programming%20csharp%20ebooks%5D.pdf&r=%241%40%242).

- `(\G(?!\A)[^][\w]+|\[)` - Group 1 (`$1`): either the end of the previous match and 1+ chars other than `]`, `[` and word chars, or a `[` char
- `(\w+)` - Group 2 (`$2`): one or more word chars.

If you only want to rename *.pdf files, replace `Get-ChildItem -File` with `Get-ChildItem *.pdf`.

Comment: Thank you. I will give that a try.

Comment: This worked really well. I can't think you enough for your help. I guess I have to put regex and powershell on my list of things to learn. Powershell I did not know it could do something like that.

Answer (score 0):

I assume there is at most one bracket-delimited substring.

You can replace zero-length matches of the following regular expression with `'@'` when using [Perl](https://www.regexplanet.com/share/index.html?share=yyyydjmaanr) (click "Perl" then check global and case-different options), [Ruby](https://rubular.com/r/OvH9Y21tnZra9q), Python's alternative regex engine, R with `perl=true` or languages that uses the [PCRE](https://regex101.com/r/JLxDyQ/3) regex engine, which includes PHP. With the exception of Ruby, the case-different (`\i`) and general (`\g`) flags need be set. Ruby only requires the case-indifferent flag.

```
r = /(?:^.*\[ *|\G(?<!^)|[a-z]+ +)\K(?<=\[| )(?=[a-z][^\[\]]*\])/
```

If using Ruby, for example, one would execute

```
str = "csharp 8 in a nutshell[studying programming csharp ebooks].pdf"
str.gsub(r,'@')
  #=> "csharp 8 in a nutshell[@studying @programming @csharp @ebooks].pdf"
```

I believe all of the languages I named above allow one to run a short script from the command line. (I provide a Ruby script below.)

The regex engine performs the following operations.

```
(?:                : begin non-capture group
  ^.*\[ *          : match beginning of string then 0+ characters then '['
                     then 0+ spaces
  |                : or
  \G               : asserts the position at the end of the previous match
                     or at the start of the string for the first match
  (?<!^)           : use a negative lookbehind to assert that the current
                     location is not the start of the string
  |                : or
  [a-z]+ +         : match 1+ letters then 1+ spaces
)                  : end non-capture group
\K                 : reset beginning of reported match to current location
                     and discard all previously-matched characters from match
                     to be returned
(?<=               : begin positive lookbehind
  \[|[ ]           : match '[' or a space
)                  : end positive lookbehind
(?=                : begin positive lookahead
  [a-z][^\[\]]*\]  : match a letter then 0+ characters other than '[' and ']'
                     then ']'
)                  : end positive lookahead
```

---

Another possibility (illustrated with Ruby) is to break the string into three pieces, modify the middle one, then rejoin the pieces:

```
first, mid, last = str.split /(?<=\[)|(?=\])/
  #=> ["csharp 8 in a nutshell[",
  #    "studying programming csharp ebooks",
  #    "].pdf"]
first + mid.gsub(/(?<=\A| )(?! )/,'@') + last
  #=> "csharp 8 in a nutshell[@studying @programming @csharp @ebooks].pdf"
```

The regex used by `split` reads, "match a (zero-width) string that is preceded by `'['` (`(?<=\[)` being a *positive lookbehind*) or is followed by `']'` (`(?=\])` being a *positive lookahead*.) By matching zero-width strings `split` does not remove any characters.

`gsub`'s regex reads, "match a zero-width string that is at the start of the string or is preceded by a space and is followed by a character other than a space (`(?! )` being a *negative lookahead*). It could alternatively be written `/(?<![^ ])(?! )/` (`(?<![^ ])` being a *negative lookbehind*).

A variant:

```
first + mid.split.map { |s| '@' + s }.join(' ') + last
  #=> "csharp 8 in a nutshell[@studying @programming @csharp @ebooks].pdf"
```

---

I created a file named `'in'` that contains the following two lines:

```
Little [Miss Muffet sat on her] tuffet
eating her [curds and] whey
```

Here is an example of a (Ruby) script that could be run from the command line to perform the necessary replacements.

```
ruby -e "File.open('out', 'w') do |fout|
          File.foreach('in') do |str|
            first, mid, last = str.split(/(?<=\[)|(?=\])/)
            fout.puts(first + mid.gsub(/(?<=\A| )(?! )/,'@') + last)
          end
        end"
```

This produces a file named `'out'` that contains these two lines:

```
Little [@Miss @Muffet @sat @on @her] tuffet
eating her [@curds @and] whey
```